# C Array Assigning Problem / CS50 Score Calculator

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I try to learn C with CS50 and try to write an exam score calculator. I have tried to write a dynamic code as below but I got error. This is my main code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int total_exam = 3 ;  // Now we are creating a constant

//Prototype
//int get_scores(void);

int main(void)
{
    // get exam scores
    int *all_scores;
    all_scores = get_scores();

    printf("Your average score is %f\n", average(total_exam, all_scores) );

}

// create an function to get exam scores of the user

int *get_scores()
{
    //get exam scores of the user

    int scores[total_exam];

    for (int i=0;i< total_exam; i++)
    {
        scores[i] =  get_int("What's your exam score?: "); // each int uses 4 byte space
    }

    return scores;
}

// create an function to calculate average

float average(int length, int array[])
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0 ; i<length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum+array[i];
    }

    return sum / (float) length ;
}
```

But when I try to execute it, I got error as below.

```
scores_with_array.c:14:18: error: implicit declaration of function 'get_scores' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    all_scores = get_scores();
                 ^
scores_with_array.c:14:16: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
    all_scores = get_scores();
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
scores_with_array.c:16:42: error: implicit declaration of function 'average' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("Your average score is %f\n", average(total_exam, all_scores) );
                                         ^
scores_with_array.c:16:42: error: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("Your average score is %f\n", average(total_exam, all_scores) );
                                  ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  %d
scores_with_array.c:22:6: error: conflicting types for 'get_scores'
int *get_scores()
     ^
scores_with_array.c:14:18: note: previous implicit declaration is here
    all_scores = get_scores();
                 ^
scores_with_array.c:33:12: error: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'scores' returned [-Werror,-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return scores;
           ^~~~~~
scores_with_array.c:38:7: error: conflicting types for 'average'
float average(int length, int array[])
      ^
scores_with_array.c:16:42: note: previous implicit declaration is here
    printf("Your average score is %f\n", average(total_exam, all_scores) );
                                         ^
7 errors generated.
```

I guess it's about array assigning but I could not understand it. Can you please help on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to return an array in C. But I am also open if you have any suggestion. I found this one : https://codeforwin.org/2017/12/pass-return-array-function-c.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Why is your prototype for `get_scores` commented? It's causing the implicit declaration problem. And it's also wrong, it should be `int *get_scores(void);`.
2. The prototype for the `average` function is not present. C assumes it returns an `int`, which is causing more problems.
3. Why are you returning the `scores` array, after the function exits, the stack gets destroyed and memory leaks can happen. Allocate it like this: `int *scores = malloc(sizeof(int) * total_exam)`.

Your code is kind of a mess, so I won't be surprised if further problems persist. Also, feel free to ask for clarifications by commenting.

Comment: The commented prototype for `get_scores` is also wrong.